# Pandas - Convert one column which is having list to different Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe having col2's value being list like

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

`col1    col2
0   1   [a, b, c]
1   2   [d, e, f]`

I want to convert col2 to a new dataframe

I was able to do like this...

```
Dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,df3.shape[0]):
    dff = pd.DataFrame(df3.col2[i]).T
    Dataframe = Dataframe.append(dff)
Dataframe
```

`.   0  1   2
 0  a   b   c
 0  d   e   f`

But wondering is there any better way/any Function to convert that column to a new datafarme.?

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame(df.col2.tolist())`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.col2.tolist(), df.index)` to preserve the index